# How to emit undefined/null value to client with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, socket.io

I recently discovered that the [socket.io](https://socket.io/) parser seems to strip keys with undefined/null values from emitted data objects. This is undesirable as i'm trying to use these values to clear information from my views.

Does anyone know a work around for this? The API allows you to provide your own parser but i'd prefer not to go down that route or alter the defualt parser ([socket.io-parser](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-parser)).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also need to send undefined value.

Comment: @c.bear the best work around solution i found was to map undefined/null values to a string representation of undefined/null before sending it down the socket. Something like: `val != null ? val : "N/A"`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this specific behavior. A quick workaround could be to always send a boolean parameter `isUndefined` or `isNull` and check it at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Same behaviour is observed on `JSON.stringify()` (which I suspect socket.io is using) and also `undefined` is not a valid JSON token.

You could replace undefined with whatever you want before sending.
Either as null or as some custom string and do the necessary checks on the other end

```
const dataToEmit = { something: undefined };

const replaceWith = null;
const s = JSON.stringify(dataToEmit, (k, v) => v === undefined? replaceWith : v );
const dataParsed = JSON.parse(s)

socket.emit("channel_name", dataParsed);
```